# Anyone know exactly why in 'The Secret Hour' it's only Bixby, Oklahoma that has midnighters?

Tags: midnighters-trilogy

In [Scott Westerfield's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott_Westerfeld) '[The Secret Hour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Secret_Hour)', is it just Melissa who can reach the whole world during the aforementioned hour?

Comment: Could you please expand your question to clarify what _exactly_ you are asking? I have no idea what you are talking about, but in its current state this question will likely be downvoted and put on hold. You might want to provide some background.

Comment: I've edited the question with some links and rephrasing to try to clarify; feel free to revert if you disagree.